# Position div below other div, except when height exceeds

Tags: css, height

I have an outer div, with a height of 400px;

In this div, I have several UL's with a dynamic height (variable amount of LI's per UL).

I want the divs to be vertically positioned first, and if it doesn't fit, the UL should be placed next to the div (right).

So, let's say first UL has 100px height, second UL has height of 250px, third one 300px.

The first and second one should be placed on top of each other (100 + 250 < 400). The third one, should be added right to the first one.

How can I achieve this with CSS/HTML (wihout JS). 
I now have this:

```
.outer {
height: 400px;
width:100%;
float:left;
background-color: yellow;
}
.element {
background-color:red;    
float:left;
overflow:show;
}
```

Current fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9c9a58n/

Comment: You cant do this as CSS is left to right _first_ then top to bottom. You will have to use JS if you want to accomplish this. But if there would be a way I'm missing, I'd be interested as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3 columns and remove your `float`s,
e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ossym8zr/2/

```
.outer {
    height: 400px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow;

    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
     columns:3;
}


.element {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 33%;
}
```

When no room is available on a column, the next list will be placed in the adjacent column. You may adjust the number of columns and their width.

If you also want to avoid a break inside a list then you can use

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
```

As stated on http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn, CSS3 columns are widely supported (except on `IE < 10`)

---

Another approach is `display: flex` forcing both a column alignment and a wrap on multiple columns (axis)
e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/wfsyqnpz/1/

```
.outer {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

The support of the flexbox module across the browsers  is really close to CSS3 `columns` but it requires to carefully declare all the syntax variations implemented on various browsers. see http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for further information

Comment: Well color me schooled. Neat solution, got to look into this a bit more.

Comment: you could use also `display :flex` anyway